# some issue with margin in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

need some help. How to fix bug with .half-img2{ margin-top: 10px; }
http://prntscr.com/94uqok

These 2 imgs height must be equal to main-img
http://plnkr.co/edit/Dvj5HfG6hJqvYPxr0ljJ?p=preview
Html:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .test{
            display: flex;
        }
        .test>div{
            flex: 1;
        }
        .test .main-img{
            flex-grow: 2;
        }
        img{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .half-img{
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .half-img2{
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        </style>
<div class="test">
            <div class="main-img">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder">
            </div>
            <div class="half-img">
                <div class="half-img1">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder">
                </div>
                <div class="half-img2">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want spacing between the two small images? If not add `float:left` to your `img` tags

Comment: yes sir, i need spacing http://prntscr.com/94uyal

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore the images sizes as these are not really relevant to the div layout issue.

A judicious use of margins and flex-column div layout seems to be required.

Layout would be something like this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border:1px solid green;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.test div {

}

.main-img {
  flex:2;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.half-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 250px;
}

.half-img {
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.half-img div {
  flex:1;
  background: lightblue;
}
.half-img1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.half-img2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
            <div class="main-img">

            </div>
            <div class="half-img">
                <div class="half-img1">
                  </div>
                <div class="half-img2">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```